# Macro vs Inline

Tags: c++, c, c++11

1. Can someone explain difference between Inline functions & Macro with example  ?
2. Which should be used when ?
3. Is it correct to say macro are also Inline (True / False)

Although there are many answers to Macro vs Inline , I am still unclear on these questions.

Comment: Please only tag one language tag, that is relevant to your question.

Comment: it is relevant to all languages tagged !  @GenoC

Comment: The proposed duplicate goes into differences and has examples. If the explanation of when to use each is not clear, use this rule of thumb: Macros Are Evil. Your third question is probably based on a misunderstanding of what "inline function" means in C++. (It does not mean a function whose body is inserted at each call site.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inline functions are functions. They just have an additional `inline` attribute to hint the compiler that it might be good to inline those functions as an optimization. It's been said that compilers might not even listen to that. From your point of view, inline functions are 100% equal to functions. It's an optimization technique for the compiler.
   Macros are code-generation templates. You define a template such as `#define ADD_ONE(x) x = x + 1;`, and the preprocessor (not the compiler) will simply replace those strings by your template strings. Macros means "string-substitution" (with a few rules).
2. Macros should be your last recourse. Use them when you would otherwise repeat code that doesn't need to be repeated.
3. True and false. Macros are simply string-substitution. So the code is inline. Inline functions may not be inline (see #1), therefore they are not "also" inline. I should add that inline means that there is no function call made while running that code.